# .NET 5 based API deployed on Azure App Service replies with 404 Not Found

Tags: azure, redirect, iis, swagger, http-status-code-404

I have .NET Core based backend application (Swagger API) deployed in Azure App Services at https://myapi.azurewebsites.net
It works fine except of one method where I invoke a redirection to another website via GET request in browser as following:
https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Method/Ext&RedirectUrl=https://externalsite.com

The link above shows Error 404 Not Found in a browser and I see that one "/" is missing from the RedirectUrl in IIS logs so this must be the reason:

> GET /api/Method/Ext&RedirectUrl=https:/externalsite.com

The IIS error code is the same - 404.

There is no Application Gateway or anything else that can modify the URL.
I checked my App Services instance configuration and did not find any settings that could modify the URL.
Did anyone experience the same issue?

Comment: if you can set the `&RedirectUrl` as `?RedirectUrl=https://externalsite.com` ?

Comment: if I set "?" instead of "&" the Swagger shows the following in a browser: "No authentication handler is registered for the scheme"

Comment: hmmm, `&RedirectUrl=externalsite.com`, then if we can remove the `https://`?

Comment: I tried that and it works. However it's still a question where the second "/" goes.

Comment: I'm afraid it related to the convert, so if you'd like to use `https://` maybe you can try `https%3A%2F%2F`, if this worked, then the issue can be located.

Comment: I also tried URL encoded version and result is the same, and in IIS log I can see the same situation : one "/" is missing in the resulting URL.